# Concept of 'shape' in clustering

Tags: clustering

Is there any abstract definition for 'shapes' of a cluster?

I am currently working on providing for a set of axioms to study clustering. In my work, I have found a need for an abstract definition for 'shape'. I wish to know if indeed there is such a definition.

I have searched for the existence of said definition and have found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape):

I wish to know if there are other definitions.